# Link to gfortran for mex file

Tags: matlab, gcc, compiler-errors, cygwin, armadillo

I am trying to create `mex` files for using some C++ code in Matlab, but running into an error with the compilation which, I guess, goes beyond Matlab. I am on Windows.

The example I'm struggling with is the *Mex Interface* example in the Armadillo library for linear algebra, available: [here](https://gitlab.com/conradsnicta/armadillo-code/tree/9.200.x/mex_interface). The Matlab file is what I'm running and it looks like this:

```
% Compile the demo as a mex file
mex -lgfortran armaMex_demo.cpp -I/path/to/armadillo
```

The error I get is:

```
Error using mex
MEX cannot find library 'gfortran' specified with the -l option.
 MEX looks for a file with one of the names:
 libgfortran.lib
 gfortran.lib
 Please specify the path to this library with the -L option.
```

Trying some things I found online, I installed MinGW and cygwin64 and added the paths to their bin folders to my `PATH` variable. Before that I also installed MinGW via Matlab.

My question: How do I get it to link with `gfortran`?

If I search `C:`for `libgfortran` I find some files, but none of them have the file ending `.lib` (but e.g. `.dll` and `.a`) and if I search for `gfortran`I find some `.exe` files but again, no `.lib` file. If I run `gfortran -dumpversion` in the terminal, I get `4.9.3` back, so it is obviously there somewhere. I am obviously missing something, and this is really not my forte, to say the least.

Comment: have you installed gfortran?

Comment: @AnderBiguri When installing cygwin I added whatever gfortran package available I could find, and `gfortran -dumpversion` in the terminal returns `4.9.3` so it should be there.